# hide actual link referrers like google

Tags: redirect, hyperlink, get, http-referer

I used to keep track of incoming search terms in my blog. I used to do it by getting the referrer, and then extracting the searched query. I knew Google used to handle links with a JavaScript event, so it changed the referrer after redirecting. But I didn't know that even actual links on Google had no **HTTP Referer**.

For example I open "https://www.google.com/search?q=referrer" in *Mozilla Firefox*, and I edit the HTML with a tool like *Firebug*, or *inspector*, and insert a hyperlink to a script that shows the referrer or extracts the searched terms. 
I know it's part of Google's privacy policy, not to include searched terms in the referrer. But I really want to know how this is possible, and how it's done.

How can I change the referrer for every link on my website? I mean actual links. Not those handles with JavaScript, or redirects.

Does the server, or some JavaScript code tells the browser, not to send an "**Http-referer**" header, while sending a **GET** request? Again, I'm not looking for a redirecting solution.

Could it be that they add a `rel="noreferrer"` attribute to every link with JavaScript? I haven't checked their scripts yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the links in Google search results, you'll see that they don't actually point to the result sites, but to an internal Google URL.  For example, [in a search for 'test'](https://www.google.com/search?q=test), the first result (at least for me) is

[Speedtest.net by Ookla - The Global Broadband Speed Test](http://www.speedtest.net/)

But the href on this link actually points to

```
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.speedtest.net%2F&ei=6ykzU774HujisAT1uYG4Bg&usg=AFQjCNHr6YyAkpiq37Q1AYAxF9ZW18CZrw&bvm=bv.63738703,d.cWc&cad=rja
```

Notice this link doesn't contain your query.  The data-href attribute on the link contains the actual URL.  There is also some javascript run on mouse down that may contribute.

The point is, it is this interim page that redirects, thus the referrer you see when the user hits your site doesn't contain any keywords.  If you want to implement it, you'd have to cookie the user, store their queries/destination in a session variable, and build a redirect script that uses this to send them off.

Comment: I already know that. I mentioned I didn't mean that in my question. I mean, even if you add an actual link with your inspector in that page, that won't have a 'Referer' either. Read my question again, and try what I just said...

Comment: Then it's very likely that their javascript is doing the redirect- after you change the href attribute and click the link, you still get directed to the internal Google URL and sent to your destination.  It doesn't matter if it's by javascript or by href directly, the extra jump is what removes the referrer with the query in it.  rel="noreferrer" wouldn't be bulletproof enough- not all browsers support it, and users could modify their browsers to ignore it.  Don't trust the user in this case.

Comment: Look, I'm not just changing the href and leaving all the IDs and classes and events to the link. I add a new link. A totally new anchor tag which is like this: <a href="url to my script">click!</a>. Just try what I said. Even after deleting the whole page, including scripts and everything in the inspector, it happens. Seriously, try it now. It keeps happening. How is that possible? How do I do it?